# Flutter Dev Tools - show request payload

Tags: android, rest, flutter, networking, devtools

With Flutter Dev Tools on Android I can see:

- request headers
- response
- response headers
- cookies

How can I show request payload for POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for requests then you can use [pretty_dio_logger](https://pub.dev/packages/pretty_dio_logger/example) to log requests. It provides very helpful logs including request payload that you require.

Comment: Yep, dio interceptor is the only rescue in this case. I use something similar to log network traffic

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external lib called Flutter Stetho. It isn't the Dart Dev Tools, but it solved my problem when I needed. This link can help you: [Flutter — Easily inspecting HTTP Request/Response Payloads and SharedPreferences](https://medium.com/@valiodas/flutter-inspecting-http-request-response-payloads-and-sharedpreferences-dbd3d0cc309e)

Comment: That library is dead and abandoned for long time. It even does not compile with latest Flutter version. Second, recent Chrome update breaks Stetho support, you can't see anything anymore

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I used a few months ago and i didn't know it was abandoned